# How to Return a value of Zero for null Value in Count Query in MS-Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two Opening Types that I am trying to retrieve counts for in my query in MS-Access. As seen in the photo below.  When either both of those values are present in my results they will produce the quantity of how many position are in for each.

[image: Opening Types]

When one of the opening types has not been selected at all on the respected table it does not show on the query count as seen below.

[image: Only 1 category displaying]

My SQL is as follows

```
SELECT tblOpening.fk_OpeningTypeId
    ,Count(tblOpening.Position) AS CountOfPosition
FROM tblOpeningCity
INNER JOIN tblOpening ON tblOpeningCity.OpeningCityID = tblOpening.City
WHERE (
        ((tblOpening.Position) = "Flex Officer")
        AND ((tblOpening.Closed) = No)
        AND (
            (tblOpeningCity.OpeningCity) = "Livermore"
            OR (tblOpeningCity.OpeningCity) = "Pleasanton"
            )
        )
GROUP BY tblOpening.fk_OpeningTypeId;
```

I have tried changing the join and no luck. Any Help would be appreciated.

Here is some sample data that is similar to what my database would use.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1X1W-wctcP7SiYIOWx4VYTOh03zddF81r

Comment: in *what way* did you try changing the `JOIN`?  by changing the tables being `JOIN`ed?  by changing the `JOIN` conditions?  by trying various flavors of `OUTER JOIN`?   please be more specific;  also, please set up a SQL Fiddle, or provide schema and data *as text* so that someone who wants to help can help you readily

Comment: I tried different types of the Outer join.  I also just added a link to a sample database of some of the information that I have.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want using a `LEFT JOIN`.  MS Access makes it hard to incorporate the difference conditions, so this probably does what you want:

```
SELECT o.fk_OpeningTypeId, Count(oc.OpeningCityID) AS CountOfPosition
FROM tblOpening as o LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT oc.*
      FROM tblOpeningCity oc
      WHERE oc.OpeningCity IN ("Livermore", "Pleasanton")
     ) as oc
     ON oc.OpeningCityID = o.City
WHERE o.Position = "Flex Officer" AND
      o.Closed = No
GROUP BY o.fk_OpeningTypeId;
```

It is possible that the filters on `o` are removing what you want.  If so, then conditional aggregation will fix that:

```
SELECT o.fk_OpeningTypeId, 
       SUM(IIF(oc.OpeningCityID IS NOT NULL AND
               o.Position = "Flex Officer" AND
               o.Closed = No, 1, 0)
          ) AS CountOfPosition
FROM tblOpening as o LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT oc.*
      FROM tblOpeningCity oc
      WHERE oc.OpeningCity IN ("Livermore", "Pleasanton")
     ) as oc
     ON oc.OpeningCityID = o.City
GROUP BY o.fk_OpeningTypeId;
```

[Access Database Sample](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1X1W-wctcP7SiYIOWx4VYTOh03zddF81r)

Answer (score 0):

Just add your condition with an `IIF()` statement like that and put a `Sum()` around it:

```
SELECT tblOpening.fk_OpeningTypeId
,Sum(IIF(tblOpening.Position = "YourCondition", 1, 0)) AS CountOfPosition
FROM tblOpeningCity
INNER JOIN tblOpening ON tblOpeningCity.OpeningCityID = tblOpening.City
WHERE (
    ((tblOpening.Position) = "Flex Officer")
    AND ((tblOpening.Closed) = No)
    AND (
        (tblOpeningCity.OpeningCity) = "Livermore"
        OR (tblOpeningCity.OpeningCity) = "Pleasanton"
        )
    )
GROUP BY tblOpening.fk_OpeningTypeId;
```