# How to Return a value of Zero Value in Count Query in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two Opening Types that I am trying to retrieve counts for in my query in MS Access as seen in the image below.

When either both of those values are present in my results they will produce the quantity of how many position are in for each.

[image: Opening Types]

When one of the opening types has not been selected at all on the respected table it does not show on the query count as seen below.

[image: SQL Results]

Here is a copy of my SQL

```
SELECT 
    tblOpening.fk_OpeningTypeId, 
    Count(tblOpening.Position) AS CountOfPosition 
FROM 
    tblOpeningCity INNER JOIN tblOpening ON 
    tblOpeningCity.OpeningCityID = tblOpening.City
WHERE 
    tblOpening.Position = "Flex Officer" AND 
    tblOpening.Closed = No AND
    (
        tblOpeningCity.OpeningCity = "Livermore" OR 
        tblOpeningCity.OpeningCity = "Pleasanton"
    )
GROUP BY 
    tblOpening.fk_OpeningTypeId;
```

I have tried using different types of outer join with no luck.

Here is a sample data that is similar to what my database would use.

I am new to SQL, please do not use short hand.

[Sample Database](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1X1W-wctcP7SiYIOWx4VYTOh03zddF81r)

Comment: Do you have a table of possible opening types? Perhaps `tblOpeningTypes`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Return a value of Zero for null Value in Count Query in MS-Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53235077/how-to-return-a-value-of-zero-for-null-value-in-count-query-in-ms-access)

Comment: It is but no one was continuing to respond to my updates.

Comment: There is a link of a sample database that you should be able to download to see what I am working with.  If you take a look at that, it might be easier to see where I can update the changes.  Take a look at the query

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a table `tblOpeningType` include it into the query and use a left join which shows all the records from the left table. Also, since you apply a where clause to the right table, this would ruin the effect of the LEFT JOIN. Therefore I use a sub-select.

```
SELECT
    T.OpeningTypeId,
    Count(X.Position) AS CountOfPosition
FROM
    tblOpeningType T
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            O.fk_OpeningTypeId AS OpeningTypeId,
            O.Position
        FROM
            tblOpening O
            INNER JOIN tblOpeningCity C
                ON O.City = C.OpeningCityID
        WHERE
            O.Position = "Flex Officer" AND
            O.Closed = No AND
            (C.OpeningCity = "Livermore" OR C.OpeningCity = "Pleasanton")
    ) X
    ON T.OpeningTypeId = X.OpeningTypeId
GROUP BY T.OpeningTypeId;
```

When two tables are joined, INNER JOIN yields results where there is a corresponding record in both tables. LEFT JOIN yields results for all the records of the left table and when records are missing in the right table, the corresponding result columns are filled with NULL.

Example:

```
Person              City
------              ----
Id Name CityId      Id Name
-- ---- ------      -- -------
1  Joe  10          10 Atlanta
2  Sue  10          20 Boston
3  Tim  30          30 Chicago
```

A INNER JOIN query:

```
SELECT c.Id, c.Name AS City, p.Name AS Person
FROM City c INNER JOIN Person p ON c.Id = p.CityId
```

Result:

```
Id  City     Person
--  -------  ------
10  Atlanta  Joe
10  Atlanta  Sue
30  Chicago  Tim
```

With a LEFT JOIN (City is the left table in this query):

```
SELECT c.Id, c.Name AS City, p.Name AS Person
FROM City c LEFT JOIN Person p ON c.Id = p.CityId
```

Result:

```
Id  City     Person
--  -------  ------
10  Atlanta  Joe
10  Atlanta  Sue
20  Boston   <NULL>
30  Chicago  Tim
```

Now, your query shows an additional difficulty. It says `WHERE tblOpening.Position = "Flex Officer" ...`. This disallows `tblOpening.Position` to be NULL in the result set (even if the column is not in the select-list), as a LEFT JOIN with `tblOpeningType` would require. Therefore I use the SELECT with this WHERE-clause as a sub-select. A sub-select is simply a SELECT command enclosed in brackets `(SELECT ...) X` with a given alias (`X`) that is used like a table in a surrounding query.

Comment: Hello Oliver.  Thank you for your response.  I hate to ask you this but I am really new to SQL.  Would you be able to expand on some of the short hand you used.

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment, assuming you have a separate table of all possible opening types (e.g. `tblOpeningTypes` with primary key `id`), then I would suggest the following:

```
select
    ot.id, nz(t.cnt, 0) as positions
from
    tblopeningtypes ot
    left join
    (
        select o.fk_openingtypeid, count(o.position) as cnt
        from tblopening o inner join tblopeningcity oc on o.city = oc.openingcityid
        where
            o.position = "Flex Officer" and
            o.closed = no and 
            oc.openingcity in ("Livermore", "Pleasanton")
        group by o.fk_openingtypeid
    ) t
    on ot.id = t.fk_openingtypeid
```